# SiteMap Navigation and Query String

Tags: c#, asp.net, dynamic, sitemap

Currently I am trying to figure out how I can add dynamic query string parameters to my sitemap navigation menu.  For example, the user chooses the source and edition he wants to work with.  I have a simple sitemap that creates navigational links but the parameters the user chose need to be passed in the query string. The default map looks like this:

```
<siteMapNode url="" title=""  description="" >
   <siteMapNode url="~/Image.aspx?location=Our Products" title="Our Products" description="Our Products" />
   <siteMapNode url="~/Headline.aspx?location=Our Authors" title="Our Authors"  description="Our Authors" />
</siteMapNode>
```

Now the links will need to have the parameters added dynamically depending on what was chosen by the user. For example:

```
<siteMapNode url="~/Image.aspx?location=Our Products&Source=12345&Edition=asdfff" title="Our Products"  description="Our Products" />
<siteMapNode url="~/Headline.aspx?location=Our Authors&Source=12345&Edition=asdfff" title="Our Authors"  description="Our Authors" />
```

Hopefully this is fairly clear.  Let me know if anyone needs deeper explanation.

Thanks

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Unfortunately, this is not supported by default. But you can implement the `SiteMap.SiteMapResolve` event in your `Global.asax` to catch such extended urls, and call `SiteMapProvider.FindSiteMapNode` with the correct url:

```
private void Application_Start(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    SiteMap.SiteMapResolve += ResolveCustomNodes;
}

private SiteMapNode ResolveCustomNodes(object sender, SiteMapResolveEventArgs e)
{
    // catch ~/Image.aspx and ~/Headline.aspx
    if (e.Context.Request.AppRelativeCurrentExecutionFilePath.Equals(
        "~/Image.aspx", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase)
      || e.Context.Request.AppRelativeCurrentExecutionFilePath.Equals(
        "~/Headline.aspx", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
    {
        string location = context.Request.QueryString["location"];
        if (location != null) // ignore everything except location=
            return e.Provider.FindSiteMapNode(
                e.Context.Request.AppRelativeCurrentExecutionFilePath
                "?location=" + HttpUtility.UrlEncode(location));
    }
    return null; // use default implementation;
}
```

No need for custom `SiteMapProvider`s, this works with any provider.

Now, if you want to be more dynamic, you can do several things, for example (there are may ways):

Flag all `<siteMapNode>` tags with partial querystring matching with a special attribute, and load this list by iterating the entire sitemap. The problem with that approach is that this can be very inefficient for some sitemap providers (the file-based provider is an example of a provider that is a good match for such an approach). What you'd do then, is to say something like

```
<siteMapNode url="~/Image.aspx?location=Our Products"
             queryStringField="location"
             title="Our Products" description="Our Products" />
```

In code you could find such nodes recursively by starting at the root node, and remembering all nodes with a `queryStringField` attribute:

```
private IEnumerable<SiteMapNode> FindNodesWithQueryString(SiteMapNode node)
{
    if (node["queryStringField"] != null)
        yield return node;
    foreach (SiteMapNode childNode in node.ChildNodes)
    {
        foreach (SiteMapNode matchingNode in FindNodesWithQueryString(childNode))
        {
            yield return matchingNode;
        }
    }
}
```

With this list in hand, and some hand waving, you should be able to do the same trick. Note that you should probably need to cache this list, because the `SiteMapResolve` event can be called more often than you'd expect. Especially for database-type `SiteMapProvider`s.

```
private SiteMapNode ResolveCustomNodes(object sender, SiteMapResolveEventArgs e)
{
    string path = e.Context.Request.AppRelativeCurrentExecutionFilePath;
    foreach (var candidate in from node in FindNodesWithQueryString(
                                                              SiteMap.RootNode)
                              select new {
                                  Url = node.Url,
                                  UrlNoQuery = node.Url.Split('?')[0],
                                  QueryStringField = node["queryStringField"],
                                  Node = node
                              } into x
                              where path.Equals(x.UrlNoQuery, 
                                             StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase)
                              select x)
    {
        string paramValue = context.Request.QueryString[
                                                    candidate.QueryStringField];

        if (paramValue != null)
        {
            string url = candidate.UrlNoQuery + "?" + candidate.QueryStringField
                       + "=" + HttpUtility.UrlEncode(paramValue);
            if (url.Equals(candidate.Url, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
                return candidate.Node;
        }   
    }
    return null;
}
```

Comment: True, that works for two pages with query strings, but it doesn't seem very flexible as you have to manually code each page with query strings.

Comment: True, but you can also use your Web.sitemap to flag such urls, if you want it to be more dynamic. I'll update the post with an example.

Comment: Getting this error `The name 'x' does not exist in the current context...` over here `QueryStringField = x.Node["queryStringField"]`

Comment: @BrijeshGandhi: oops; that should read `node["queryStringField"]`. Fixed.

Answer (score 0):

The default SiteMap provider in ASP.NET doesn't allow for query strings unfortunately.

This is a problem many people have came across - it's easy enough to write your own provider however that has query string functionality.

The provider below has worked well for me for several years.

http://www.csharper.net/blog/custom_sitemapprovider_incorporates_querystring_reliance.aspx

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue related to using a base64, url encoded string as a query parameter in the site map. Simplest solution was to just handle the MenuItemDataBound event and do my encoding there:

```
    string[] url = e.Item.NavigateUrl.Split('?');

    if (url.Length == 2)
    {
        url[1] = WebUtils.encodeString(url[1]);
    }

    e.Item.NavigateUrl = string.Join("?", url);
```

My webutils method:

```
    public static string encodeString(string value)
{
    return HttpUtility.UrlEncode(Convert.ToBase64String(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(value)));
}

public static string decodeString(string value)
{
    return Encoding.UTF8.GetString(Convert.FromBase64String(HttpUtility.UrlDecode(value)));
}
```